# launch progress bar instantly in zk

Tags: progress-bar, zk

i start with zk and i have a problem, when i run an action zk automatically starts a progress bar, but it launches it one or two seconds after the triggering of the action. So I would like to know if there is a way to change this launch time of the progress bar so that it is instantaneous.

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you are doing? It will be easier to provide advice.

Comment: I will edit m’y question and i will post some part of my code

Answer (score 0):

When I read this, I have a feeling you send a request to the server. The server is busy for 2-3 seconds and afterward you tell the client to put up a progress bar. This all is in 1 request so it's normal that you see it after 2-3 seconds because your request isn't returned before that.

So in practice you should do : 
 1. First request => create the progress bar, finish the request.
 2. Make a second request => do your code that take 2-3 seconds.

This is all in the line of long operations and [Robert Wenzel from ZK has written a very good small talk](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/January/Simplify_Long_Operation_Handlings) about that.
You could use his code from the small talk and you have a setup in your project for all your long operations.

Comment: thank you @chillworld, I found this subject of Robert Wenzel very rewarding. but what I do is not a long operation. my action is that when the user clicks on a button example I run the loader bar I do not see why it takes 1 to 2 seconds